# RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I  have the following code which throws me error:

> RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to
>   function has reached maxfev = 1000

I think it is due to the def func in the loop.
How can it be fixed?

I am using curve_fit from scipy and I want to find better values for many independent groups.

I is working WITHOUT LOOP perfectly.

thanks!

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.


 df_fit = pd.DataFrame()

for (group, df_gp) in df.groupby(['label']):

df_gp.sort_values(['animal']).reset_index(drop=True)

if len(df_gp) > 0:
    if len(df_gp) % 2 == 0:
        df_gp = pd.concat([df_gp, df_gp.tail(1)], axis=0); 

    x = np.arange(1,len(df_gp)+1)
    y = df_gp['price']

    xx = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(), len(df_gp))

    # interpolate + smooth
    itp = interp1d(x,y, kind='linear') #kind = 'linear', 'nearest' (dobre vysledky), slinear (taky ok), cubic (nebrat), quadratic - nebrat
    # window size must be odd
    window_size, poly_order = len(df_gp), 2
    yy_sg = savgol_filter(itp(xx), window_size, poly_order)

    def func(x, A, B, x0, sigma):
        return A+B*np.tanh((x-x0)/sigma)

    fit, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y)
    yy_fit = func(xx, *fit)

    #fit1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 3))
    #df_gp = df_gp.drop_duplicates(subset= 'sku',keep = 'first', inplace =True)

    # pridani promennych do dataframe
    df_gp['yy_fit'] = yy_fit
    df_gp['yy_sg'] = yy_sg
    df_fit = pd.concat([df_fit,df_gp], axis = 0)    

df_fit = df_fit.sort_values(['sku']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: have you tried increasing maxfev? curve_fit(func, x, y, maxfev=5000)

Comment: Yes, then I have      TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Comment: but where? I use that syntax and have no problems with curve_fit

Comment: do you use exact same - like I posted? it says that df_gp is none but in df is only one group

Comment: what line triggers the typeError?

Comment: now ihave: raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m)) 
TypeError: Improper input: N=4 must not exceed M=3

Comment: that doesn't pertain to the original question. You wanted to fix maxfev, that is solved. Ask another question but first fix your code

Comment: Increasing `maxfev` likely wont fully solve the underlying problem. The issue is likely that your parameters, perhaps `sigma` span many orders of magnitude. Given your data, you should try to scale your fit parameters so they are relatively close to one, and so you don't have `A~7` while, `sigma~10**-18`. On the other hand, you could also provide an initial guess (`p0` keyword) for such difficult functions, which will typically help the fit.